# Oracle's Equivalent to DEFAULT in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, oracle

This is not a question about default column values, rather the 'DEFAULT' database objects in SQL Server databases.

I'm writing a tool to convert T-SQL scripts to Oracle scripts. How should I deal with the existing `DEFAULT` creation scripts?

I have thought about creating a stored function that returns the same value, then using a synonym to keep the references working.

One of the create default scripts looks like so:

```
CREATE DEFAULT [dbo].[DF_Color_Alpha]
AS 255;
```

Comment: And how is this default used?

Comment: I have no clue. I recursively searched the directory of scripts. I can't find a caller. It's a removal candidate but should be replicated for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect that the closest equivalent would be a package variable

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE my_constants
AS
  color_alpha constant integer := 255;
END my_constants;
```

You could then reference `my_constants.color_alpha` in your code.  A function, presumably as part of the same package, that returned the value would also be a reasonable option.

Comment: This is worth a shot. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Ah. Because I'm writing a script to translate the SQL, I'll have to write logic to resolve data types. Notice how the DEFAULT didn't have one. Any suggestions there.

Comment: @Ray - Any translation is going to require that you specify a data type.  I would guess that all your defaults are either `integer` or `varchar2(n)` for some reasonably small value of `n` so then it's just a matter of checking whether the value is numeric to determine which to use.

Comment: A package variable wont work because it can't be accessed outside of the package. I'll have to write a helper function to return the value. Then, references won't be maintained because the call with have parenthesis.

Comment: Huh?  A variable defined in the spec of the package (as I showed here) is visible outside the package.  A variable would only be private to the package if it was defined only in the body of the package.  Your constants package probably doesn't need a package body at all.  If you do have a package body, it should probably only have an initialization section if there are variables whose values are not constant but should come from the environment.